# Long to wide data

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape, tidyr

I have been trying to reshape some data from long into the wide format. I am interested in having one row per unique ID. To mimic my requirements, I have created a sample input and the desired output as below:

##### Input:

```
id   date   size    category    name    type
124  3.1      1     fruit       apple   royalGala
327  1.1      0     veg         chilli  green
124  2.1      2     fruit       apple   green
124  1.2      1     fruit       apple   jazz
124  2.2      2     fruit       apple   eve
124  2.1      3     fruit       apple   pinkLady
327  1.2      1     veg         chilli  red
327  1.2      2     veg         chilli  Jalapeño
327  1.2      3     veg         chilli  bananaPepper
327  3.3      1     veg         chilli  fresnoPepper
```

##### Output:

```
id  fruit_apple_royalGala_date  fruit_apple_royalGala_size  fruit_apple_green_date  fruit_apple_green_size  fruit_apple_jazz_date   fruit_apple_jazz_size   fruit_apple_eve_date    fruit_apple_eve_size    fruit_apple_pinkLady_date   fruit_apple_pinkLady_size   veg_chilli_green_date   veg_chilli_green_size   veg_chilli_red_date veg_chilli_red_size veg_chilli_Jalapeño_date    veg_chilli_Jalapeño_size    veg_chilli_bananaPepper_date    veg_chilli_bananaPepper_size    veg_chilli_fresnoPepper_date    veg_chilli_fresnoPepper_size
124 3.1                         1                           2.1                     2                       1.2                     1                       2.2                     2                       2.1                         3                           NA                      NA                      NA                  NA                  NA                          NA                          NA                              NA                              NA                              NA
327 NA                          NA                          NA                      NA                      NA                      NA                      NA                      NA                      NA                          NA                          1.1                     0                       1.2                 1                   1.2                         2                           1.2                             3                               3.3                             1
```

I am unsure how to achieve the desired output. I have looked at some relevant questions at StackOverflow but none of them help me solve this problem e.g., [Convert data from long format to wide format with multiple measure columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589693/convert-data-from-long-format-to-wide-format-with-multiple-measure-columns), [From long to wide data with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37332076/from-long-to-wide-data-with-multiple-columns) and [Reshape multiple value columns to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608167/reshape-multiple-value-columns-to-wide-format).

I have been working on this problem since yesterday but having very little experience with gather and spread etc., I have not been able to solve it. I would greatly appreciate any assistance on this.

Thank you!

##### dput()

For convenience, I am also copying dput()

```
structure(list(
id = c(124L, 327L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 327L, 327L, 327L, 327L), 
date = c(3.1, 1.1, 2.1, 1.2, 2.2, 2.1, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 3.3), 
size = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), 
category = c("fruit", "veg", "fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "fruit", "veg", "veg", "veg", "veg"), 
name = c("apple", "chilli", "apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "chilli", "chilli", "chilli", "chilli"), 
type = c("royalGala", "green", "green", "jazz", "eve", "pinkLady", "red", "JalapeÃ±o", "bananaPepper", "fresnoPepper")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

##### Partial Solution

I have a work around to solve this problem but my solution fails when I run it on my original data.

```
# Read the csv file
df = read.csv("C:/Desktop/test.csv")

# Unite multiple columns in to one
df_unite = df %>% 
  unite("info", category:type, remove = TRUE)

# Conversion from long into wide format
setDT(df_unite)   # coerce to data.table
df_wide <- dcast(df_unite, id ~ info, 
                value.var = c("date", "size"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id, c(category, name, type), 
            values_from = c(date, size),
            names_glue = '{category}_{name}_{type}_{.value}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. A quick question, is there a way to keep the column ordering intact? For example, columns are sorted by type where date and size appear next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's absolutely possible to sort your long pivot data so that all the dates show up first, followed by all the sizes. `pivot_wider` actually provides this functionality.

Just add `names_sort=TRUE` to @Onyambu's function above. It will look like this:

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id,c(category,name,type),
              values_from = c(date, size),
              names_glue='{category}_{name}_{type}_{.value}',
              names_sort=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I actually wanted the columns to be sorted as given in the output section above.

```fruit_apple_royalGala_date``` comes before ```fruit_apple_royalGala_size```

And similarly for the other entries.